# How to import JS file wrapped in IIFE into TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, module, client-server

I have a TS file, and I want to import the functionality of a JS library that is wrapped in an IIFE. The library currently exposes its functionality by setting properties on the window object. How can I import this library into TS? I've tried adding `exports` before each function, but I get the error `file is not a module`. Should I just bite the bullet and copy the code over manually?

To avoid the XY problem, I'm making a website, and both the front and back end have some common functionality that they need to perform. I'm looking into a serverless back end using TS. If that's an anti-pattern and I should do something else entirely, I'll accept that as an answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a particularly elegant way to do this, but I got the functionality I wanted by returning the specific functions I need from the anonymous function and exporting the results of the IIFE.
Like so:

JS Library (I added the `export default` and the `return { ... }`)

```
export default (function () {
    function foo() { ... }
    function bar() { ... }
    function baz() { ... }
    ...

    // the library makes some functions available to the window
    window['baz'] = baz

    // I manually export the functions I need
    return {
        'foo': foo
        'bar': bar
    }
})()
```

TS file:

```
import lib from './library.js'
lib.bar()
```

I also had `"esModuleInterop": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file

Answer (score -1):

I accomplished this by publishing and installing an NPM package that contains a custom definition for a library and then tweaking the tsconfig.json to allow it.

1. Create an `index.d.ts` file in the same directory as your IIFE library .js file
2. In `index.d.ts`, add the single line: `declare var libname = require('libname');`
   For example:

```
declare var identikon_cljs = require('identikon_cljs');
```

3. Publish it as an npm organization or user scoped package: https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages
4. Install the package in your project (e.g. `npm i @mpm/identikon --save`)
5. Add or set the following compilerOptions as true to prevent a TypeScript complilation error stating "Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts":

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true
    }
}
```

6. Import the library in your component like so:

```
import '@mpm/identikon';
```

7. You may then access properties and methods of the library as though it was exported as a module. Here is an example of a directive I made:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, } from '@angular/core';
import '@mpm/identikon';

@Directive({
    selector: '[identikon]'
})
export class Identikon {

    @Input() width: number = 64;
    @Input() height: number = 64;
    @Input() set identikon(value: string) {
        if (value) {
            let id = 'identikon-' + value + '-' + new Date().getTime().toString();
            this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute('id', id);
            identikon_cljs.core.make_identikon('#' + id, this.width, this.height, value);
        }
    };

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

}
```

8. Then I could bind it with ease in an Ionic 2/3 project like so:

```
<ion-avatar [identikon]="user.avatar" [width]="32" [height]="32" item-end></ion-avatar>
```